# Just imported my image, Need a sub panel on the right

Tags: java, import, panel

Just imported an image, but need a subPanel on the right with the dimensions (200,700) I've tried using the imported image as a panel but it just spans me with errors, any ideas?

```
package dodge;


import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Dodge extends JFrame {
    private ImageIcon image;
    private JLabel label; 


      Dodge(){
          JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          frame.setResizable(false);
          frame.pack();
          setLayout(new FlowLayout());
          JPanel image = new JPanel();


          image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Road.jpg"));
          label = new JLabel (image);
          add(label);

      }  


public static void main(String[] args) {
        //

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.pack();

        Dodge gui = new Dodge();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.pack();
        gui.setTitle("Dodge The Cars");

        JPanel subPanel1= new JPanel();
        subPanel1.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        subPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (250,700));
        JLabel label = new JLabel ("Menu");
        subPanel1.add(label);
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 JFrames in your code. You create a frame in the main method. Then you create a Dodge class which is a JFrame. Finally in the constructor of the Dodge class you create another frame.

I suggest your read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for working examples that will show you how to better structure your program. Then it should be easier to solve your problem.